# Random initial velocities within Plummer model in Python

Tags: python, physics

I want to randomly distribute *N* particles within a volume such that they satisfy the Plummer potential distribution. I trying to work from "The Art of Computational Science" by Hut, which has a description but I can't seem to implement it. Where I differ from Hut is that I require 3 velocity components for each particle. Here's what I have done so far:

```
f=0
g=0.1
if g >f*f*(1-f*f)**3.5:
    f=np.random.uniform(0,1,N)
    g=np.random.uniform(0,0.1,N)

vel_x= f*np.sqrt(2)*(1+x*x)**(-0.25)
vel_y= f*np.sqrt(2)*(1+y*y)**(-0.25)
vel_z= f*np.sqrt(2)*(1+z*z)**(-0.25)

vel = np.zeros((N,3))
vel[:,0]=vel_x
vel[:,1]=vel_y
vel[:,2]=vel_z
```

However, when I run the energy check described by Hut, such that the kinetic energy ~0.147 in N body units, this code fails. Any advice on where Im going wrong would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably misreading the Ruby code in Hut's book since it is also generating 3-dimensional velocity vectors:

```ruby
x = 0.0
y = 0.1
while y > x*x*(1.0-x*x)**3.5
  x = frand(0,1)
  y = frand(0,0.1)
end
velocity = x * sqrt(2.0) * ( 1.0 + radius*radius)**(-0.25)
theta = acos(frand(-1, 1))
phi = frand(0, 2*PI)
b.vel[0] = velocity * sin( theta ) * cos( phi )
b.vel[1] = velocity * sin( theta ) * sin( phi )
b.vel[2] = velocity * cos( theta )
```

The first part generates |**v**| by rejection sampling from the velocity distribution. The second part generates a random direction in space (in polar coordinates) and the last part of the code transforms from polar to Cartesian coordinates.

Your code does something completely different. You should instead adapt the code fragment shown above in Python, e.g.:

```
f = 0.0
g = 0.1
while g > f*f*(1.0-f*f)**3.5:
  f = np.random.uniform(0,1)
  g = np.random.uniform(0,0.1)
velocity = f * np.sqrt(2.0) * (1.0 + radius*radius)**(-0.25)
theta = np.arccos(np.random.uniform(-1, 1))
phi = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi)
vel[n,0] = velocity * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
vel[n,1] = velocity * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
vel[n,2] = velocity * np.cos(theta)
```

The code could possibly be vectorised, but in reality it makes little sense since the rejection sampling is not vectorisable (it might and most likely will take different number of iterations for each sample).

Comment: sorry what is n in the context of vel[n,0]?

Comment: The code is part of a loop body. `n` is the index of the particle currently being created.